# How do I enable database level authentication in redis deployment

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I am using redis cluster deployment in the Kubernetes. I would like to enable authentication for database level (I assume redis supports multiple databases with in the cluster.)

Answer (score 0):

[Redis Cluster does not support multiple databases like the standalone version of Redis.](https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/)

Moreover, for what it's worth, [enabling authentication](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/) for database level, irrespective of the mode (standalone/sentinel/cluster), is not supported (yet).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If Redis sentinal support multiple databases, can we enable authentication for database level?

Comment: could you please correct me if i am wrong. Is standalone redis and redis sentinal both are same?

Comment: "If Redis sentinal support multiple databases, can we enable authentication for database level?" - No. updated answer.

Comment: "Is standalone redis and redis sentinal both are same?" - In many terms, YES. E.g. exactly one node accepting writes, multiple databases, etc.